# trying to remove an element from an array and add positive integers python

Tags: python

I am working on my programming skill and I am caught up on removing a negative element from the array and adding the rest of the elements. My Idea was to evaluate each element to see if they are negative or not. If they are, take it out of the array. Here is what I got so far.

```
 arr = [1,-2,3,4,5]

for a in arr:
    if a > 0:
         #i need to remove the element if it is equal
```

Comment: To help your programming skills, I'd probably recommend reading the docs and trying some of the methods: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

You might learn more that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but this should filter your array's negative numbers and only leave the positive ones:

```
arr = [a for a in arr if a > 0]
```

Comment: This will also discard `0` elements.  It's not clear if that's the desired behavior (although it is consistent with the code stub that OP posted).

Comment: so I am looping through each element and if the loop "sees" a negative number, it takes that number out of the list so I can do what I need to with it. When I try to do either a.remove() or arr.remove() it complains.

Comment: @keelsinit: Yeah, don't do that. Mutating a `list` while iterating it is both slow and wrong (you'll skip elements for testing, such that for a pair of negative numbers, only the first is removed). This answer gives the correct solution: A list comprehension that creates a new `list` with only the numbers you want to keep, rather than removing the numbers you don't want. If you need to mutate the original list in place (so aliases of it see the change), just do `arr[:] = [a for a in arr if a > 0]` instead (which replaces the *contents* of the old `list` with the contents of the new).